# "Invalid configuration" error when using python-arabic-reshaper package with Pyinstaler

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller to put an exe wrapper around a Python 2.7 script that imports Python package python-arabic-reshaper, the script works fine when running by itself, but ends in the error below if run from within a Pyinstaller exe.

The config file is default-config.ini and configparser package is installed.

Code:

```
import sys
from arabic_reshaper import ArabicReshaper

config1={
    'delete_harakat':False,
    'support_ligatures':True,
    'RIAL SIGN':True,
}

reshaper=ArabicReshaper(configuration=config1)
text=u"????"
reshaped_text=reshaper.reshape(text)

print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(reshaped_text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Error:

```
F:\HisHands\Yang>F:\HisHands\Yang\dist\bob_test_1.exe
WARNING: file already exists but should not: C:\Users\Ownerc\AppData\Local\Temp\
_MEI153402\include\pyconfig.h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 13, in 
  File "C:\Users\Ownerc\Downloads\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\lo
ader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "F:\HisHands\Yang\build\bob_test_1\out00-PYZ.pyz\arabic_reshaper", line 1
, in 
  File "C:\Users\Ownerc\Downloads\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\lo
ader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
  File "F:\HisHands\Yang\build\bob_test_1\out00-PYZ.pyz\arabic_reshaper.arabic_r
eshaper", line 1377, in 
  File "F:\HisHands\Yang\build\bob_test_1\out00-PYZ.pyz\arabic_reshaper.arabic_r
eshaper", line 1248, in __init__
ValueError: Invalid configuration: A section with the name ArabicReshaper was no
t found
```

I also used the archive viewer tool to view the content of the executable generated, shown below

```
pos, length, uncompressed, iscompressed, type, name
[(0, 170, 235, 1, 'm', u'struct'),
 (170, 1153, 2704, 1, 'm', u'pyimod01_os_path'),
 (1323, 4222, 11804, 1, 'm', u'pyimod02_archive'),
 (5545, 6034, 18956, 1, 'm', u'pyimod03_importers'),
 (11579, 1589, 4450, 1, 's', u'pyiboot01_bootstrap'),
 (13168, 347, 504, 1, 's', u'bob_test_1'),
 (13515, 48403, 89416, 1, 'b', u'VCRUNTIME140.dll'),
 (61918, 39529, 87552, 1, 'b', u'_bz2.pyd'),
 (101447, 624405, 1443840, 1, 'b', u'_hashlib.pyd'),
 (725852, 76667, 146432, 1, 'b', u'_lzma.pyd'),
 (802519, 28814, 66048, 1, 'b', u'_socket.pyd'),
 (831333, 888894, 2045440, 1, 'b', u'_ssl.pyd'),
 (1720227, 10439, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1730666, 10253, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1740919, 10265, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1751184, 10322, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1761506, 11406, 22208, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1772912, 10289, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'),
 (1783201, 10419, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'),
 (1793620, 10290, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1803910, 10469, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1814379, 10302, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1824681, 10532, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1835213, 11178, 21184, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'),
 (1846391, 10461, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1856852, 10395, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1867247,
  10555,
  19648,
  1,
  'b',
  u'api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1877802, 11078, 20672, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1888880, 10498, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'),
 (1899378, 10215, 18112, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1909593, 10486, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1920079, 10347, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1930426, 10870, 20672, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1941296, 10524, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'),
 (1951820, 10598, 19648, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1962418, 10376, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1972794, 10274, 18624, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1983068, 10607, 19648, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (1993675, 11729, 22720, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2005404, 10429, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2015833, 11063, 20672, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2026896, 10584, 19648, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2037480, 10540, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2048020, 13628, 27840, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2061648, 10654, 19648, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2072302, 11901, 23232, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2084203, 12357, 24768, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2096560, 12530, 24768, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2109090, 11174, 21184, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2120264, 10601, 19136, 1, 'b', u'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll'),
 (2130865, 485, 1035, 1, 'b', u'bob_test_1.exe.manifest'),
 (2131350, 74629, 189952, 1, 'b', u'pyexpat.pyd'),
 (2205979, 1637554, 3938304, 1, 'b', u'python35.dll'),
 (3843533, 9127, 19968, 1, 'b', u'select.pyd'),
 (3852660, 446584, 982720, 1, 'b', u'ucrtbase.dll'),
 (4299244, 341035, 865792, 1, 'b', u'unicodedata.pyd'),
 (4640279,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  'o',
  u'pyi-windows-manifest-filename bob_test_1.exe.manifest'),
 (4640279, 197523, 761033, 1, 'x', u'base_library.zip'),
 (4837802, 1198430, 1198430, 0, 'z', u'out00-PYZ.pyz')]
?
```

Thanks